# How to send Acknowledgement?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I'm working on a C# application, sending information over a TCP connection.

The customer has asked for a specific way to send/receive and acknowledge messages: upon every message, ASCII value 6 should be send as an acknowledgement.

In order to do so, I'm simply sending 6 over the TCP socket, and I believe this is wrong:

This is what I do:

```
char? acknowledge; // it gets value 6 (in the watch-window, I see "6 '\u0006'").
Own_Object.Send(new byte[] { (byte) acknowledge });
```

`Own_Object` is of class `Own_Class`, which has following method:

```
public bool Send(byte[] data)
...
int i_result = _socket.Send(data, data.Length, 0);
                // in the watch-window, data = "{byte[1]}", data type = "byte[]".
                // data[0] is of type "byte", and has value 6.
```

Using Wireshark (on both sides) I see this byte being sent and arrive, but there always is a `[TCP spurious retransmission]` behind it, so I believe I'm doing something wrong.
Also, another network monitoring program (socket Workbench) does not capture the send of the acknowledgement, so I believe I'm doing something wrong indeed.

Does anybody know what I can do in order to send an acknowledgement correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you've got your offset and length parameters for `_socket.Send` in the wrong order.

Comment: @spender that looks fine to me. The `0` at the end is equivalent to `SocketFlags.None` and maps to this signature: [`int Send (byte[] buffer, int size, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags socketFlags)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.send?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Sockets_Socket_Send_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Net_Sockets_SocketFlags_)

Comment: @AndreasHassing Indeed. I was going from memory. Apologies for the misinfo.

Comment: @Dominique: do you mean the ASCII character `'6'` or just the byte value for `6`? They're two different things, [see this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7AHwAEAmARgFgAoaosgTgApHgBPDGASgHIAdHAAxCk3TgG5aDZmw48R4oA=).

Comment: @AndreasHassing: I do mean `'\u0006'`, the byte value for 6 (according to Wikipedia), this stands for "Acknowledgement", see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Comment: Hmm.. TCP already implements ACK as a part of the protocol. What is the point of adding yet another ACK? Can you give more details about what you and the customer are trying to get to?

Comment: The customer has asked for this type of communication: one side sends a message, ended by '\u0003' (end of text) and at reception, the other party responds with '\u0006' (acknowledgement), and so forth. It's just a way to confirm that both parties understand each other correctly without depending on already existing networking features.

Comment: The thing which I find disturbing, is the constant extra message mentioning the TCP spurious retransmission. It's like TCP thinks something is fishy about this character `byte 6` and TCP feels it needs to act on it, while I just want TCP to send that character without doing anything else.

Comment: I see this is the second time you've asked this. Are you sending the ack either on a different socket, or after disconnect?

Comment: As already pointed out by @AndreasHassing above, `ASCII value 6` is not `\u0006` but rather `\u0036`, so which one do they want? -- As for your last comment the socket does not treat any particular byte values transmitted within the message body as special in any way.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: by `ASCII value 6` I mean the character, whose ASCII value is 6, so I'm talking about `\u0006`.

Comment: FWIW, that's quite a roundabout way of setting a byte variable to 6.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: The declaration of `Socket.Send()` needs `byte[]` as an input parameter. What's an easier way to send 6 in such a case?

Comment: How about `Own_Object.Send(new byte[] { 6 });`?

Comment: The bottom line is that wireshark shows the byte was sent and received. There is no problem then, a few spurious retransmission are nothing to worry about.